# Compare time portion of datetime values in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to compare only the time portion of datetime values in sql.

I have tried it with the following way,

```
 DECLARE @t1  smalldatetime
 SET @t1=CAST('1900-01-01 '+CONVERT(varchar(8),@saledate,108) As smalldatetime) 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 SELECT Model FROM  Sales WHERE @t1 between WorkStart  and WorkEnd And Ctrl=@key
```

'WorkStart' and 'WorkEnd' is a DateTime field and the date portion always contains '1900-01-01'.

And the parameter @saledate is a datetime, how can i compare only the time portion without consider the date portion of @saledate,workstart and workend.

The table already created the WorkStart and WorkEnd with DateTime field and i cannot modify the field datatype as it is currently being used.

Comment: I think you need to specify your database... datetime functions change from db to db.

Comment: What is the version of your server? Is `CAST(@saledate AS TIME)` possible?

Comment: @Sanoj: Execute this statement `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer, you can cast to TIME datatype to compare the time portion.

```
SELECT Model 
FROM Sales 
WHERE 
  CAST(@saledate AS time) BETWEEN CAST(WorkStart AS time) AND CAST(WorkEnd AS time) 
  AND Ctrl = @key
```

If you do that often, it would be more performant to have your times stored to database columns as TIME, not DATETIME.